# How to match with optional occurence?

Tags: java, regex

For the construct `{123{a,b}}` I want to match `{123{` and `}}`.

This is done by regex: `{(.*?){|}}`

BUT: now I want to use the same expression to run on `{a,b}` and match `{` and `}` only.

Therefore I somehow have to make the 2nd `{` optional. But how?

I'm using http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to test on the fly.

Comment: can you list the example strings that you need to match.

Comment: Would you have just two levels of nesting?

Comment: Well I just want to match `{123{`, but also the same regexpression should be able to match only `{`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following regex:

```
(?:{.*?)?{|}}?
```

This makes all the content outside the inner braces optional.

```
(?:{.*?)?   // Contents before the opening inner brace '{' (Optional)
 {   
   |
 }
}?          // Last brace (Optional)
```

See demo on http://regexr.com?35t3r

Comment: That indeed works, thanks. One more question: how could I for instance include the both `&&` characters optionally in front of the curly brackets like in your example? This does not work: `(&&)?(?:{.*?)?{|}}?`

Comment: @membersound. I don't understand? Do you want to match an optional `&&` in front of both the patterns?

Comment: @membersound. Your regex should work actually. that's correct.

Comment: Ok, I modified it to `([&\s])+?(?:{.*?)?{|}}?` to match any number of `&` and whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

What about, for example

```
/{(123{)?/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{(.*\\{|[^\\}]*)");
        Matcher matcher1 = pattern.matcher("{123{a,b}}");
        Matcher matcher2 = pattern.matcher("{a,b}");

        while (matcher1.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher1.group());
        }
        while (matcher2.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher2.group());
        }
```

> Output:
>  {123{
>   {a,b